# Python networkx, how do I add x amount of edges per node?

Tags: python, networkx

I have a basic network graph in python using networkx, what I want to do is add a specific amount of edges per node, not directly determine the edges myself.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

hosts = 100
nodes = list(range(1,(hosts+1)))

H=nx.Graph()
H.add_nodes_from(nodes)
nx.draw_random(H)
```

[image]

So with this graph what I would like to do is specify "two edges per node" and then let python calculate the result. Is this possible?

Many thanks.

Comment: Do you want to add two edges per node so that the total number of edges is two times the number of nodes, or do you mean so that each node has degree 2?

Comment: It can be done, but not by default. You have to write code for it. Do you care which node connects to which, or could it all be random for all you care?

Comment: @kaya3, I want to have 2 degrees per node with no loops.

Comment: @Reti43, that is good to know, for now I think that it can be random connections, but there needs to be 2 edges per node.

Comment: When I left my comment, I didn't know that the method in the answer below existed. I would have simply reinvented the wheel, but you can do this simply with `H = nx.configuration_model([2] * hosts)`. The nodes will be numbered from 0 by default, but you can [remap them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64103507/how-to-rename-a-single-node-of-a-networkx-graph). If there is something unsatisfactory about the answer provided, you can ask for further clarification there.

Comment: Thank you, all comments have been incredibly helpful.  I think your answer is completely satisfactory. However, if something further is needed I will ask!

Comment: If Fony Lew's has resolved your issue, consider marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question sounds like a concept of configuration model in graph where it will return a random graph with the given degree sequence.

See the [networkx.generators.degree_seq.configuration_model](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.generators.degree_seq.configuration_model.html) documentation

For example of a graph with degree [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

H = nx.configuration_model([i for i in range(5)])

nx.draw_random(H)
```

Note that sum of degrees must be an even number.
[image: Configuration model with degree from 0 to 4]